# Cascade Delete turned on?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to check if the table(s) have Cascade Delete turned on?  I'm looking at the script of the table (from SQL Server) and I don't see any indication of Cascade Delete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229277/sql-server-2008-get-table-constraints

Comment: *Tables* don't have cascade delete turned on, per se. Foreign Key constraints do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use `sys.foreign_keys` for foreign key relations.

The column - `delete_referential_action` helps you know if there is a delete on cascade.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx

Below View help with similar works:

```
sys.default_constraints for default constraints on columns
sys.check_constraints for check constraints on columns
sys.key_constraints for key constraints (e.g. primary keys)
sys.foreign_keys for foreign key relations
```

Source: [SQL Server 2008- Get table constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229277/sql-server-2008-get-table-constraints)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This is way quicker and easier than my solution.  Do you know how I can turn on Cascade Delete on a FK that has a delete_referential_action = 0 and a delete_referential_action_desc = 'NO_ACTION'

Answer (score 33):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA for standard approach, ex.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
where DELETE_RULE ='CASCADE'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do this:

I scripted the FK on the table to a new query window:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_myTable_myTableHeaders] FOREIGN KEY([ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[myTableHeaders] ([_ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

This how I was able to confirm it.