# How to get Tablename ,ForeignKey and Constraints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have written the Query in which i am getting TableName,Columns,Precision but how can i get Table related Foreign key and Constraints

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(tb.[schema_id])) AS 'Schema',
    QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(tb.[OBJECT_ID])) AS 'Table',
    C.NAME AS 'Column',
    T.NAME AS 'DataType',
    C.max_length,
    C.is_nullable,
    c.precision,
    c.scale

FROM SYS.COLUMNS C
INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES tb ON tb.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
INNER JOIN SYS.TYPES T ON C.system_type_id = T.user_type_id
WHERE tb.[is_ms_shipped] = 0 
ORDER BY tb.[Name]
```

Suugest me

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008- Get table constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229277/sql-server-2008-get-table-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
And OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'TableName'
```

Or you might try this also (ref: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/summarize-all-constraints-table)

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(constid) 'Constraint Name',
  constid 'Constraint ID',
  CASE (status & 0xF)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Primary Key'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Unique'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Foreign Key'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Check'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Default'
    ELSE 'Undefined'
  END 'Constraint Type',
  CASE (status & 0x30)
    WHEN 0x10 THEN 'Column'
    WHEN 0x20 THEN 'Table'
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END 'Level'
  FROM sysconstraints
  WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('TableName')
```

more details as follow

**By referencing this question [SQL Server 2008- Get table constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229277/sql-server-2008-get-table-constraints)**

You should use the current sys catalog views (if you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer - the sysobjects views are deprecated and should be avoided) - check out the extensive MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation on catalog views here.

There are quite a few views you might be interested in:

- `sys.default_constraints` for default constraints on columns
- `sys.check_constraints` for check constraints on columns
- `sys.key_constraints` for key constraints (e.g. primary keys)
- `sys.foreign_keys` for foreign key relations

and a lot more - check it out!

You can query and join those views to get the info needed - e.g. this will list the tables, columns and all default constraints defined on them:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    dc.Name,
    dc.definition
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
```

Comment: along with my query how can i get the  constraints and foreignkeys with in the query