# SQL query to get primary keys for all tables in sybase ase 15.x along with column names

Tags: sql, constraints, sybase, sap-ase, unique-constraint

I'm using Sybase ASE 15.5 and a stranger to this database.
Straight to the point-->
I'm looking for a sql query that would help me get the primary keys for all tables in sybase along with the column names on which the primary key is declared. 
For example,
if I have the following tables,
organization having primary key PK_org_id on the column org_id
org_alias having primary key PK_alias_id on the column alias_id
org_temp having primary key PK_org_temp_id on the columns (org_id,org_name)

then the query should return me with:

- Table_Name     PK_Name         Column_name
- Organization   PK_org_id       org_id
- Org_alias      PK_alias_id     alias_id
- Org_temp       PK_org_temp_id  org_id,org_name

I've tried the below query:

```
select  o.name , i.name
from   sysobjects  o,   sysindexes   i   
where o.id=i.id  
and i.indid = 1  
and o.type = 'U'
```

but it only returns me the table name with its primary key.
I want to have the column name too.

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229277/sql-server-2008-get-table-constraints

Answer (score 1):

Use the built_in function `index_col(object_name, indexid, N [,owner_id])`. 
This lets you retrieve the Nth column of a particular index. Call it multiple times with different values for N, for example by joining it with `master..spt_values` where type = 'P' and supplying the number column as N.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rob. I'm looking specifically for a sql query that would output me the table name, primary key name and the columns on which it is defined. Can you also share that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to code your own query, then look at the catalog procedures that are included with ASE. 'sp_pkeys' should give you what you want.