# command to know table has a primary key along with table name in sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am using sybase as I am new to sybase prior to that I have used oracle now I have an database which consists of many table in sybase now there is a table named tarty now can you please advise the command that I can execute in sybase to know is there any primary key is there in tarty table or not .

here i got the solution for this..

```
select name     
from sysindexes
where indid > 0
and status2 & 2 = 2
```

Can you also please advise that i want the table name also to be get listed for example the above command will show the primary key only i want the primary key plus the table name also to be listed so that i can know that this primary key belongs to this table please advise what necessary changes i need to do to achieve this..!

Comment: It's helpful to tag your question with the software product and version you are running, or include it in your question.  Sybase was a company that produced multiple database products, and not all the syntax is the same.  I have added the [sybase-ase] tag to your question, based on the tables you are querying.

Answer (score 1):

Including the table name is easy:

```
select name, object_name(id) as table_name
from sysindexes 
where indid > 0
and status2 & 2 = 2
```

Also see "[SQL query to get primary keys for all tables in sybase ase 15.x along with column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967142/sql-query-to-get-primary-keys-for-all-tables-in-sybase-ase-15-x-along-with-colum/)" for a related discussion. There's a catalog query `sp_pkeys` that's included with ASE that you can use or borrow from.