# How to get names of all SQL Server Defaults and Rules

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, rules, defaults

I'm trying to write a query to get the names of all Rules and Defaults in the database so I can programatically drop all of them from a database without having to know their names.

They don't seem to be contained in `sys.objects`, though - so where can I find them?

[image: Rules and Defaults]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229277/sql-server-2008-get-table-constraints

Comment: @squillman both of the answers there return no rows for me. I think that they only show where the rules/defaults are used, as opposed to the actual definitions themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.objects
WHERE  type = 'r' -- to filter rules
        OR ( parent_object_id = 0 -- to restrict default constraints 
             AND type = 'd' ) -- to filter defaults
```