# How to Get All Table Name, Column Name, Column Values with their Constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query it show the table name column name and column value of database i want to get the constraint of these value.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)

CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(370),ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )
  WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
     
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
     
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT '''+@TableName+''',''' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' 
            )
        END
    END   
END

SELECT Tablename,ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: this about sql.

Comment: its about sql server can you edit it for me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2008- Get table constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229277/sql-server-2008-get-table-constraints)

Comment: No I Just want to add constraint in my query.

Comment: The answers in the link do that. You can alter your query with the information from those answers. Or do you mean something else when you write `constraint` ?

Comment: I am beginner i don't know how to do that.

Comment: "Beginners" do not start learning tsql by querying the metadata of the database.  Beginners do not write dynamic sql. Beginners do not splatter code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Stop with the excuses.